# reading a file from folder using javascript

Tags: javascript

can I read the contents of a file from a certain folder using javascript??I have been trying so much research but all gives me the browse but I don't want to browse,I have the file name and folder name, and I want to have the contents of this file only.how could that happen if possible
I found this solution,but don't know what is the fs??

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {

// Get a File object representing the file,
// then use FileReader to read its contents.
fileEntry.file(function(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onloadend = function(e) {
     var txtArea = document.createElement('textarea');
     txtArea.value = this.result;
     document.body.appendChild(txtArea);
   };

   reader.readAsText(file);
 }, errorHandler);

 }, errorHandler);

}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs inside a sandbox that doesn't allow it to read files, you can try with the [FileSystem API in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) but that's also considered to become dead as browsers are not interested in supporting it.

Comment: so what do you think is the solution in my project if i want to read a file??

Comment: Check @gerald-schneider [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777201/reading-a-file-from-folder-using-javascript/24777250#comment38449517_24777201) above.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file using the latest `FileReader API` using the  following piece of code

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
    var contents = event.target.result;
    console.log("File contents: " + contents);
};

reader.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
};

reader.readAsText(file);
```

WORKING CODE [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/nDVYd/320/)

More about File Reader API:[Link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files)

Comment: as I said earlier i dont want to browse for the file, i already have the file name